# Jude's weekly salary was increased by 8% to $237.60. What was her weekly salary before the increase?

Tags: percentages

I am struggling with basic maths (trying to recap several years). Could you please help me understand the methods to achieve the answer?

I was trying something like:

x -> The initial salary
x(0.08) -> The raise
x + x(0.08) -> The salary with the raise

Therefore

x + x(8/100) = 237.60

Is there a simpler way to resolve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x$ is Jude's previous weekly salary, then:
$$x\times1.08=237.6$$

Solve for $x$, which should just be $\frac{237.6}{1.08} = 220$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! My mistake was in using x  + x1.08 rather than x + 1.08! Looks simple and elegant! Cheers